# Impressão com ReportViewer Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

Boa tarde, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Estou gerando uma impressão pelo ReportViewer com Visual Studio 2010, o relatório é gerado corretamente mas na visualização da impressão não aparece o botão Imprimir no relatório. Então resolvi converter a impressão para o PDF ai sim agora aparece a opção para imprimir, mas onde tem acento fica assim:

```
      teste de ent&#227;o         - que o certo seria - teste de então
```

Essa coluna já tentei colocar ela como Varchar ou Nvarchar e fica com o mesmo problema.

Segue o Código da pagina do relatorio:

```
ReportViewer1.Reset();
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                    // atribuiu o caminho onde está o relatorio .rdlc
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Relatorio\RelAcompanharOcorrencias.rdlc";

                    // cria e atribui o datasource
                    ReportDataSource dts = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dts);
                    //ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

                    var bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;attachment; filename=Sample.pdf");
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
                    Response.Clear();
```

Abaixo segue o Código do botão que aciona impressão:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (gridHome.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dt = ObjOcorrencia.converterGridViewParaDataTable(gridHome);
                Session["dtimpressao"] = dt;
                Redirect("Relatorio/fRelAcompanharOcorrencias.aspx","_blank","");
            }
```

Se alguém tiver uma solução tanto para colocar o botão imprimir ou pra corrigir esse problema de acentuação agradeço

Grato desde já.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado

Comment: Já está acrescentado.

Comment: Já tentou usar o método PRINT? ReportPrintDocument rp = new ReportPrintDocument(ReportViewer1.ServerReport);
  rp.Print();

Comment: Sim, mas não exibe o botão imprimir só de salvar. O botão para imprimir não exibe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O botão imprimir no ReportViewer do VS2010 só aparece no internet explorer, atualize seu projeto para o VS2013 ou VS2015, atualize as bibliotecas do reportViewer e o botão estará disponível em outros navega